# How to I extract the wallet Vault on Chrome using a command in MacBook?

Tags: metamask

I forgot my seeds phrase for MetaMask in my Macbook. I tried to follow guideline (https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351-How-to-use-the-Vault-Decryptor-with-the-MetaMask-Vault-Data) but I got an error.

Steps I did

1. Go to Extensions in Chrome
2. Right click and open Inspector
3. Go To console
4. Copy and paste below commond got from the guildline

   chrome.storage.local.get('data', result => {
   var vault = result.data.KeyringController.vault
   console.log(vault)
   })
   **** Not sure whether I put above command correctly in console.***
5. Got below error
   [image]

Please help me to recover my seeds phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got that piece of code to work by clearing cache, and then noting that the undefined still showed, but 'data' was listed in lower window, had to scroll down. next issue is github vault decryptor requires some password, that if you had it, you wouldn't be extracting your own data... catch 22. trying to solve that one. but for your issue, there are two console tabs, upper and lower, data was in lower window. but clearing browser cache fixed it for result, data.